# MySQL - Problems with rank() traduction

Tags: mysql, count, rank

I'm doing a project for my school with MySQL about a site mocking Twitter.

I've got USERs who can become EXPERTs by FOLLOWing people (in the FOLLOW table I put .followed as the mail of the one followed and .following as the mail of the one following). USERs can TWEET and see TWEETs of the USERs the FOLLOW.

One of the requested query is the following one:
*Given an Expert users A, return the user B followed by A who tweeted the most in the last week.*

I wrote this code

```
 SELECT follow.followed
 FROM follow
 INNER JOIN user ON follow.followed = user.mail         
 INNER JOIN tweet ON user.mail = tweet.mail       
 WHERE tweet.datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW() AND follow.following = 'john.doe@gmail.com'       
GROUP BY follow.followed
ORDER BY COUNT( tweet.mail ) DESC       
LIMIT 1
```

But as you can see it only shows one result, and the teacher pointed out that in case of a tied result he wants the query to return all of the tied users.

I figured out I need something like the rank() function, but I cannot "translate" it in mySQL, not even using all the solutions I found here on StackOF.

I can't understand if I'm doing something wrong or what, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Alberto